# How to demonstrate a mean of sample means using a single histogram

Tags: r, random, histogram

Suppose I have data as follows:

```
df1<-rnorm(400000, 65,10)
```

I want to draw 1000 samples of size 100 and plot a histogram using Means of Samples. In the histogram, the x-axis is "Mean" and the y-axis is "Frequency" and a Red Line shows the Mean of Samples in the middle of the histogram.

I am sorry that I could not develop a histogram to show it. I hope my description makes it clear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = replicate(1000, mean(sample(df1, 100)))
hist(d)
abline(v = mean(d), col = "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to answer the question is the following example implementation

```
a<-rnorm(1000, 5,2)

#intialize empty vector and fill with means
xbar = rep(0,250)  
for (i in 1:250) { xbar[i]=sample(a, 50) }

# make histogram
hist(xbar,prob=TRUE,breaks=12)
```

Because this question sounds suspiciously like a homework question, I've given you a partial solution above.  Make sure you know what each of these functions are doing because it will help you greatly in a long run.  You'll have to edit the above to fit the exact parameters of your question.  Likewise I'll leave the last part of your question for you to answer yourself, but you'll probably want to use [xline](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fields/versions/9.8-6/topics/xline)