# R - How to plot generated sample means?

Tags: r

I created some sample data here:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- rexp(1000, rate = 0.2)
```

Then, I created a for loop to create 1,000 sample means:

```
loop <- for (i in 1:1000) {
  sample1 <- sample(data, 5)
  mean1 <- mean(sample1)
  print(mean1)
}
```

Then, I tried to create a histogram of those sample means using this code:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(loop))
```

However, this just uses the last sample mean created (I believe). How can I better go about this?

Thank you!

Oh, also, I could create the sample means using this code as well, if it will be easier to work with:

```
fivesample1 <- replicate(1000, 
          sample1 <- mean(sample(data, 5)), 
          simplify = FALSE)
ggplot() + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(fivesample1)) # This histogram also did not work.
```

Comment: If you want to use ggplot, I'd recommend going through a tutorial first to see how it works. The official docs are very thorough & link to a lot of other tutorials. `ggplot` needs a data frame, whereas it looks like you're just printing means through the for loop

Comment: @camille Thank you for that! After you mentioned the data frame piece, it made me realize that the simplify = FALSE code I put in the replicate() function was changing the structure of the data, and removing that piece of the code made it work! My answer is below, if you would like to see the code, if my explanation was weird there. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to demonstrate a mean of sample means using a single histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039154/how-to-demonstrate-a-mean-of-sample-means-using-a-single-histogram)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Camille pointing out that ggplot needs a data frame, I remove the simplify = FALSE from the replicate() function, and it worked!

Here is what worked, to clarify:

```
fivesample1 <- replicate(1000, 
          sample1 <- mean(sample(data, 5)))
ggplot() + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(fivesample1))
```

Comment: The `sample1 <-` is redundant; `replicate` uses the value of that expression.